# Google Maps custom marker not displaying

Tags: google-maps

We did this script over a year ago, and its not displaying the marker icon. I know its gmap 2 , and should be gmap3 now.. but for the life of me cannot convert. Any help appreciated, or help us fix this issue, please.

Script is:

```
    var userLocation = '<?php echo $homelocation; ?>';

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
   var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
   geocoder.getLocations(userLocation, function (locations) {         
      if (locations.Placemark)
      {
         var north = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.north;
         var south = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.south;
         var east  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.east;
         var west  = locations.Placemark[0].ExtendedData.LatLonBox.west;

         var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(new GLatLng(south, west), 
                                        new GLatLng(north, east));

         var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));

          var Icon = new GIcon();
          Icon.image = "images/422marker.png";
          Icon.iconSize = new GSize(33, 50);

         map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
         map.addOverlay(new GMarker(bounds.getCenter()), Icon);
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: You will have to rewrite most of that, no way round it, you will have to go and read and study the docs and the examples - which are very clear.  Join the Gmaps v3 Google Group too.

Comment: Did it used to work but doesn't anymore? Or did the markers never work?

Comment: It actually works perfect, just doesnt display our custom marker.

Comment: Did the custom marker never display?  Did it only stop displaying recently?  Or has it never displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Does `&v=2` appear in your load script URL that loads the API from Google? If not, add it and the script will likely start working again.

You'll still want to take the time to upgrade to v3 at some point, of course.

Comment: Yes the version appears in the script, its just the custom marker that doesnt display, we keep getting the stardard marker pin.

Comment: Did the custom marker ever work with the v2 script?  Or is this something you've only added recently and/or it has never worked before?

Comment: that I couldnt be sure of lol. I was just goign thru all our google map scripts for the site we are doing, and noticed this wasnt displaying the custom marker